# Whats the best Http Component which supports SOCKS and HTTPS for C#.NET

Tags: http, sockets, https, httpwebrequest

Iam coding an application which needs to do some web automation to some websites from our intranet. Some are simple web services while some will be https websites. My application needs to connect to them via socks proxies.

Now httpwebrequest class does not support socks so Iam looking to code a complete HTTP wrapper using Sockets . I need suggestions from my fellow coders here on what would be a good component to use as I am not looking to re invent the wheel here, rather use some existing socket based solution, either opensource or paid components.

Any suggestions guys? I need only socket based components which support socks proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecureBlackbox includes [HTTP / HTTPS components](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-http.php) that support both HTTP proxy, HTTPS proxy and SOCKS. The components use their own socket class which can be used separately as well.

Comment: When I click on that link it gives a 404.

Comment: Thank you for pointing. It was a typo. Correct link is http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-https.php